# Compare rows from the same dataframe and update/create new columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am comparing values from different rows of the same dataframe and updating the `score` column with data from the afore matched row. The following code works fine for what I need, however it is not an efficient solution and takes hours to run for a 20K DF.

What is a faster vectorised way to achieve the same result?

I tried the below iterative method:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2022-10-01', '2022-10-02', '2022-10-03', '2022-10-01', '2022-10-02'],
                   'symbol': ['XYZ', 'XYZ', 'XYZ', 'ABC', 'DEF'],
                   'tenor': ['2022-10-31', '2022-11-30', '2022-12-31', '2022-10-31', '2022-11-30'],
                   'score': [2, 3, 4, 6, 7],
                   })
ref_symbol = 'XYZ'
df_xyz = df.loc[df['symbol'] == ref_symbol]
sym_to_compare = list(df.symbol.unique())
sym_to_compare.remove(ref_symbol)
score_columns = [f'score_{sym}' for sym in sym_to_compare]
df[score_columns] = [np.NAN] * len(sym_to_compare)

for idx, row in df_xyz.iterrows():
    for sym in sym_to_compare:
        match = df.loc[(df.symbol == sym) & (df.tenor == row.tenor) & (df.date == row.date)]
        if len(match.index):
            df.at[idx, f'score_{sym}'] = match.score
```

Dataframes before and after transform:

```
# Original DF
         date symbol       tenor  score
0  2022-10-01    XYZ  2022-10-31      2
1  2022-10-02    XYZ  2022-11-30      3
2  2022-10-03    XYZ  2022-12-31      4
3  2022-10-01    ABC  2022-10-31      6
4  2022-10-02    DEF  2022-11-30      7

# Transformed DF
         date symbol       tenor  score  score_ABC  score_DEF
0  2022-10-01    XYZ  2022-10-31      2        6.0        NaN
1  2022-10-02    XYZ  2022-11-30      3        NaN        7.0
2  2022-10-03    XYZ  2022-12-31      4        NaN        NaN
3  2022-10-01    ABC  2022-10-31      6        NaN        NaN
4  2022-10-02    DEF  2022-11-30      7        NaN        NaN
```

Comment: Maybe you can split the dataframe into many distinct ones. Each holds the rows of a distinct symbol. Then you can loop on the dataframes related to the symbols to match and create new columns on the reference dataframe through left joins on the `tenor` columns (if I understand well you business logic)

Comment: What does *updating the score column with data from the afore matched row.*  mean? I don't understand the logic that produced the "Transformed DF". Its hard to understand from your code.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the job in a faster way:

```
ref_symbol = "XYZ"
sym_to_compare = set(df["symbol"].unique()) - set([ref_symbol])
ref_df = df[df["symbol"] == ref_symbol].copy()
for s in sym_to_compare:
    curr_df = df[df["symbol"] == s]
    ref_df = ref_df.merge(
        curr_df[["tenor", "score"]]
        .rename(columns={"score": f"score_{s}"}), 
        on="tenor", 
        how="left"
     )
```

which outputs:

```
         date symbol       tenor  score  score_ABC  score_DEF
0  2022-10-01    XYZ  2022-10-31      2        6.0        NaN
1  2022-10-02    XYZ  2022-11-30      3        NaN        7.0
2  2022-10-03    XYZ  2022-12-31      4        NaN        NaN
```

You can then append again the `sym_to_compare` rows if you need them.

Comment: Thanks, Matt. I used your solution and got a significant speed boost. With the merge update, I can run through the full DF in less than a minute as opposed to a couple of hours before.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
# symbol to use as reference
ref_symbol = 'XYZ'
# columns to use a merging key
cols = ['tenor', 'date']

m = df['symbol'].eq(ref_symbol)

out = df.merge(
    pd.concat({ref_symbol: (
                df[~m].pivot(index=cols, columns='symbol',
                             values='score')
                      .add_prefix('score_')
            )}, names=['symbol']).reset_index(),
    how='left',
)
```

Output:

```
         date symbol       tenor  score  score_ABC  score_DEF
0  2022-10-01    XYZ  2022-10-31      2        6.0        NaN
1  2022-10-02    XYZ  2022-11-30      3        NaN        7.0
2  2022-10-03    XYZ  2022-12-31      4        NaN        NaN
3  2022-10-01    ABC  2022-10-31      6        NaN        NaN
4  2022-10-02    DEF  2022-11-30      7        NaN        NaN
```

Comment: I'd appreciate if you can give a feedback on the timings when you test it ;)

Comment: Have you had a chance to test it?